# Maze Traversal in java

Tags: java, algorithm, file, maze

OK so I'm done with a maze program, but the problem is it only takes an matrix of size 20x20, I programmed it to take a size 30x20 matrix but it always gives me an error like this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception: Invalid map.
    at MazeSolver.loadMaze(MazeSolver.java:73)
    at MazeSolver.main(MazeSolver.java:233)
```

Can someone please take a look at it and give me some feed back on where I messed up?

My guess is the problem lies here in the method

`private static char[][] loadMaze(String filename) throws Exception`

in the `MazeSolver` class on line 49:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MazeSolver {



    private static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    /**
     * Forces the user to enter a string
     */
    private static String readString(String prompt) {
        while (true) {
            System.out.print(prompt);
            String value = keyboard.nextLine().trim();

            if (!value.isEmpty()) {
                return value;
            }

            System.out.println("Error: Please enter a value.");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Forces the user to enter an integer
     */
    private static int readInt(String prompt) {
        while (true) {
            try {
                System.out.print(prompt);
                return Integer.parseInt(keyboard.nextLine());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Error: Please enter a numeric value.");
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Load the maze from file
     */
    private static char[][] loadMaze(String filename) throws Exception {
        // Load the maze file, we assume the file is 30 x 20
        char[][] maze = new char[30][20];

        try {
            Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File(filename));

            for (int row = 0; row < maze.length; row++) {
                String line = inFile.nextLine();

                for (int column = 0; column < maze.length; column++) {
                    maze[row][column] = line.charAt(column);

                    if (maze[row][column] != PATH && maze[row][column] != WALL && maze[row][column] != EXIT) {
                        throw new Exception("Invalid map.");
                    }
                }
            }

            inFile.close();
        } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("The file " + filename + " does not exist.");
            System.exit(0);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Exception("Invalid map.");
        }

        return maze;
    }

    /**
     * Forces the user to provide a starting coordinate
     */
    private static Coordinate readStartingCoordinate(char[][] maze) {
        int startingRow = 0;
        int startingColumn = 0;

        while (true) {
            // Read a valid row
            startingRow = readInt("Enter starting row: ");

            while (startingRow < 0 || startingRow >= 30) {
                System.out.println("Error: Please enter a value from 0 to 29");
                startingRow = readInt("Enter starting row: ");
            }

            // Read a valid column
            startingColumn = readInt("Enter starting column: ");

            while (startingColumn < 0 || startingColumn >= 20) {
                System.out.println("Error: Please enter a value from 0 to 19");
                startingColumn = readInt("Enter starting column: ");
            }

            // Make sure that the starting coordinate isn't a '1' (wall)
            if (maze[startingRow][startingColumn] == WALL) {
                System.out.println("Error: The starting point you selected is a wall");
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }

        return new Coordinate(startingRow, startingColumn);
    }

    /**
     * Solve the maze recursively
     */


        // Go down
        if (row + 1 < maze.length && (maze[row + 1][column] == PATH || maze[row + 1][column] == EXIT)) {
            path.push(new Coordinate(row + 1, column));

            if (solveMaze(maze, path)) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        // Go left
        if (column - 1 >= 0 && (maze[row][column - 1] == PATH || maze[row][column - 1] == EXIT)) {
            path.push(new Coordinate(row, column - 1));

            if (solveMaze(maze, path)) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        // Go right
        if (column + 1 < maze.length && (maze[row][column + 1] == PATH || maze[row][column + 1] == EXIT)) {
            path.push(new Coordinate(row, column + 1));

            if (solveMaze(maze, path)) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        // If none of the directions worked, we reached a dead end
        path.pop();
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Remove all visited marks from the maze and put the correct path the
     * computer to solve it
     */
    private static void cleanMaze(char[][] maze, LinkedList path, Coordinate start) {
        for (int row = 0; row < maze.length; row++) {
            for (int column = 0; column < maze.length; column++) {
                if (maze[row][column] == VISITED) {
                    maze[row][column] = PATH;
                }
            }
        }

        Coordinate end = path.pop();
        maze[end.getRow()][end.getColumn()] = EXIT;

        while(!path.isEmpty()) {
            Coordinate coordinate = path.pop();
            maze[coordinate.getRow()][coordinate.getColumn()] = ANSWER;
        }

        maze[start.getRow()][start.getColumn()] = START;
    }

    /**
     * Print the maze with numbered row and columns
     */
    private static void printMaze(char[][] maze) {
        System.out.printf("%3s", " ");

        for (int i = 0; i < maze.length; i++) {
            System.out.printf("%3d", i);
        }

        System.out.println();

        for (int row = 0; row < maze.length; row++) {
            System.out.printf("%-3d", row);

            for (int column = 0; column < maze.length; column++) {
                System.out.printf("%3c", maze[row][column]);
            }

            System.out.println();
        }

        System.out.println();
    }

    /**
     * Entry point of the program
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Ask for the file to solve and load the maze
                String filename ="C:\\Users\\TriZam\\Desktop\\MazeFile.txt";                   //  readString("Enter maze filename: ");


        char[][] maze = loadMaze(filename);

        // Ask for starting coordinates
        printMaze(maze);
        Coordinate start = readStartingCoordinate(maze);
        LinkedList path = new LinkedList();

        // Solve the maze
        path.push(start);
        solveMaze(maze, path);

        // If map is solved print out results
        if (solveMaze(maze, path)) {
            cleanMaze(maze, path, start);
            printMaze(maze);
            System.out.println("I am free");
        } else {
            printMaze(maze);
            System.out.println("Help, I am trapped");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you understand that's ***YOUR*** exception that is being thrown?  If your code assumes a 30x20 maze but the input is only 20x20 are you expecting it to magically adapt?  You should print the stack trace of the original exception to figure out the real problem, which is likely `IndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: What does the `C:\Users\TriZam\Desktop\MazeFile.txt` file contain?

Comment: ok so i  see im out of bound.. so why?

Comment: add an `e.printStackTrace()` rather than throwing away the exception you get, and see for yourself.

Comment: i did and i get this..String index out of range: 20

Comment: but my array is clearly 30x20..i tried row.lengh +10 and error again... im lost...

Answer (score 1):

I solved it thanks to debugging. although i never used debugging i now know alot more on how to use it to found problems

Answer (score 0):

loadMaze iterates both row and col over maze.length, so  only works on square mazes.  You need to split length into two values: width and height.

Comment: i added 10 to height but still nothing